# DataTables Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, datatables

I have a repeater and wrap it all with `DataTables` library. Here is the following js function.

```
function createDataTable() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tblMessages').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sDom": '<"clreol"lf><"scrollable_datatable"rt><"clreol"ip>',
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bAutoHeight": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "bStateSave": true,
            "iCookieDuration": 60*60*24
        });
    });
}
```

I got no pagination at all just scroll bar on the right side of the repeater. And I got this on console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined jquery.dataTables.min.js:366
Y                                                        jquery.dataTables.min.js:366
(anonymous function)                                     jquery.dataTables.min.js:454
jQuery.extend.each                                       jquery.min.js:21
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each                                    jquery.min.js:12
i.fn.dataTable                                           jquery.dataTables.min.js:434
(anonymous function)                                     Message.aspx:156
jQuery.fn.extend.ready                                   jquery.min.js:26
createDataTable                                          Message.aspx:152
```

What's wrong? And what should I do?

Comment: Can anybody help me to resolve this same problem.

Answer (score 23):

Check your table structure:

- Number of columns (`th`) in `thead` section must equal number of columns (`td`) in `tbody` section. See [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML) for proper HTML structure.
- If you're using `colspan` or `rowspan` attributes for `th` elements in `thead` section, make sure that each column has one unique `th` element. See [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html) for more info and demonstration.

Comment: It is working for my case. My tfoot colspan value is not match with columns in table.

Comment: Thank you man, the problem for me was `rowspan=2`, you saved my day thanks!

Comment: In my case, it was because some of the `<tr>` in `<tbody>`  had no closure